# Reference controls on a form from a function/sub

Tags: vb.net, controls, class-library

I have a strong suspicion that what I'm wanting to do is not possible, but I could use the confirmation.

I have a Class Library that I have created to handle some common Subs & Functions that I use a lot (in some form or fashion).

Some of those Subs & Functions can take a go long while (typically in cases where records are being iterated through & processed in some fashion). In those instances I usually have had the function update a progress window (text and stepping a progress bar).

Now that I'm genericizing to put them in the class library I obviously can't anticipate a specific form or control being there. But I'd like to retain the functionality. So what I'm hoping to do is create optional input variables for the RichTextBox & ProgressBar that would be getting updated, so that I can then pass in references to the controls that should be used for statusing.

Is this possible? If so, how? When I try to define any inputs as `Windows.Forms.<anything>` Intellisense drops out (strongly hinting that I can't type them as controls).

Thanks!

UPDATE: The function I'm trying to add the references to follows, errors are indicated for either `System.Windows.Forms.<X>`

```
Public Function ResOut(ByVal D As DataTable, ByVal epath As String, ByVal SAName As String, ByVal Parent As String, ByRef PBar As System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar, _
                       ByRef RTB As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox) As String
    '
    Dim res As String = ""
    Dim E As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim x As Long = 0
    Dim f As Long = 1
    Dim s As New JMLib.Status
    Dim Rng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    'Define the range
    Rng = ws.Range("A1:" & ColNumToStr(D.Columns.Count, epath) & D.Rows.Count)
    'Create the array
    Dim OArr(D.Rows.Count, x) As Object

    'Create a workbook for the data and capture the workbook and sheet for ease of reference
    Try
        wb = E.Workbooks.Add
        ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        res = "Encountered an error while creating the new workbook to export the results to. No data can be returned."
        EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
    End Try

    'Fill in headers
    If res = "" Then
        Try
            For Each c As DataColumn In D.Columns
                ws.Range("A1").Offset(0, x).Value = c.ColumnName
                x = x + 1
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            res = "Encountered an error while filling in the column headers. This will prevent any data from being returned."
            EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
        End Try
    End If

    'Setup the step & frequency for the Step Progress bar
    'Dim t() As Long = s.StatSetup(QR.Rows.Count, 58, "Query Runner\ResOut\" & QName, Replace(My.Settings.EPath, "<user>", Environment.UserName) & DStamp() & " Query Scheduler Log.txt")
    'f = t(0)
    'SProg.Step = t(1)

    'Convert the datatable to a 2D array
    If res = "" Then
        Try
            'Fill it
            x = 0
            For r As Long = 0 To D.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
                Dim dr As DataRow = D.Rows(r)

                For c As Integer = 0 To D.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
                    OArr(r, c) = dr.Item(c)
                Next
                x = x + 1
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            res = "Encountered an error while outputing the " & x + 1 & "-th record of " & D.Rows.Count & ". No data will be output."
            EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
        End Try
    End If

    'output the array to the target range
    If res = "" Then
        Try
            Rng.Value = OArr

            'Save the workbook
            wb.SaveAs(SAName)
            wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        Catch ex As Exception
            res = "Encountered an error during the export of the results. Some data may have been exported. Review the contents of the Excel workbook that will be visible following this message for more" _
                    & " details."
            E.Visible = True
            wb.Activate()
            EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
        End Try
    Else
        'Close the workbook without saving
        wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    End If

    'Cleanup the application
    Try
        E.Quit()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(E)
        E = Nothing
        wb = Nothing
        ws = Nothing
        s = Nothing
        Rng = Nothing
        OArr = Nothing
        f = Nothing
        x = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        EL.AddErr("Encountered an error while cleaning up the resources used in JMLib\ResOut. ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
    End Try

    Return res
End Function
```

Comment: You should create Events that the clients of your library subscribe to be notified when certain actions happen. It is the job of the user interface to handle its update.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by adding references to the progress bar/text box to the Class.

When the class invoked you can set the references or not.

In the class if the reference ISNOT NOTHING I update the progress bar/textbox.

---

Nothing specific about being in a user written class - here is an example from some library code:

```
Sub DisplayParcels(aAPNs() As String,...., Optional ProgBar As ProgressBar = Nothing)
...
    If ProgBar IsNot Nothing Then
        ProgBar.Maximum = aAPNs.Length
        ProgBar.Value = 0
        ProgBar.Visible = True
    End If

...
    For Each sAPN In aAPNs
...
         If ProgBar IsNot Nothing Then ProgBar.Value = iCnt
   Next
...
    If ProgBar IsNot Nothing Then ProgBar.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You're meaning references as in `Public Function <name>(ByVal ProgressBarRef as ProgressBar)` or as in a Reference in the properties of the Class library?

Comment: As a property that can be set in an overloaded New(ByRef ...) or as a Get/Set property. When I need to report progress I just check to see if the property ISNOT NULL before updating the control.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I tried initially, the trouble I ran into is that Visual Studio throws an error on `ByRef PBar as System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar` saying `Type 'System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar' is not defined`. Is there something I could be missing (for what it's worth the class inherits nothing)? Or am I just hitting a limitation of VS Express?  The function in question has been added to the original question.

Comment: Not a limitation of Express, very few differences from the full version except it lacks team support. Are you using WinForms or WPF? Try removing the full qualified path and just use 'as ProgressBar'

Comment: The form in question is a WinForm. `As ProgressBar` gets the same error

Comment: Too much code in the original post to debug the "not defined" error. Maybe the calling routine has the problem?